# Can/should RecyclerView.Adapter have access to the ViewHolders?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-adapter

I have an`EditText`in each`View`, and in`onViewRecycled(.)`I update the item in the`Adapter`with any user input. For the purpose of maintaining the information when scrolling`Views`out of and back into view.

However, I realised that with this solution it's a bit of a hassle to retrieve the information that has been modified but not recycled. I solved this by adding each`ViewHolder`to a separate list in the`Adapter`(added in`onCreateViewHolder(.)`), since I couldn't find a simpler way to update the`Views`on the screen.

Is there any reason not to do this; let the`Adapter`have direct access to the`ViewHolders`? I.e. are there any better ways to call a function on all`Views`currently in existance?

Edit:

```
public class AdapterRv extends Adapter<AdapterRv.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Item> items;
    private List<MyViewHoders> viewHolders;

    public AdapterRv(List<Item> inItems) {
        ...

        viewHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private EditText text;
        private Item item;

        private MyViewHolder(View inView) {
            ...
        }

        public void bindItem(Item inItem) {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup inParent, int inViewType) {
        ...

        if (!viewHolders.contains(tmpHolder)) {
            viewHolders.add(tmpHolder);
        }

        ...
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder inViewHolder) {
        saveView(inViewHolder.item, inViewHolder.text.getText().toString());
    }

    private void saveViews() {
        for (MyViewHolder tmpViewHolder : viewHolders) {
            saveView(tmpViewHolder.item, tmpViewHolder.text.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    private void saveView(Item inItem, String inNewText) {
        if (inItem.getText().equals(inNewText)) {
            return;
        }
        inItem.setText(inNewText);
    }

    public List<Item> fetchTexts() {
        saveViews();
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some code, so it is self explanatory

Comment: you just call nmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); or else as @ParthAnjaria says share some code

Comment: There are various ways to notify a RecyclerView to "refresh"  it's views

Comment: Done, code added.
@cricket_007 What are those ways?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to show, but I highly doubt you need to hold onto the list of ViewHolder objects yourself. I think the RecyclerView does that behind the scenes on its own

Comment: When the`User`presses a button, the information in the`EditTexts`are needed by the app. Those that are scrolled out of sight before presing the button can be saved in the`onViewRecycled(.)`method (which also solves the problem of not reloading initial information into the`EditText`, but what's the best way to retrieve the new information entered by the`User`?

Comment: I.e. the new information that hasn't been saved in the`onViewRecycled(.)`method because the user hasn't scrolled before pressing the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` is only to create `ViewHolder` instances and provide them with data, but it is the `RecyclerView` itself that requests holders and manages them.

The purpose of the `ViewHolder` is, as it name suggests, to hold the item's view hierarchy so the `Views` can be cached and reused by the `RecyclerView`. Hence, the adapter should only create and bind the correct data to holders, and it is recommended to not store any references to holders inside the adapter, since you only need the reference to holder in the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position` method, where it is provided by the `RecyclerView`. It's also vice-versa, the view holders don't need a reference to the adapter, so your `MyViewHolder` should be marked `static`.

If you need to operate on recycler's views, the `RecyclerView` has plenty of methods in it's API, such as `findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int position)`, `getChildViewHolder(View child)` etc. You can also set listeners for observing scroll, item touch, view attach state etc. changes.
[See the documentation for the RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

So, if you need to access and manipulate the views (ie. call the function on all of recycler's views), do it through the `RecyclerView` and not the adapter, because it's the recycler that manages them - adapter only provides data.

Comment: `"The purpose of the ViewHolder is, as it name suggests, to hold the item's view hierarchy so the Views can be cached and reused by the RecyclerView."` it is done by `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler`, ViewHolder and view reusing are two different things, ViewHolder purpose is for an easy child view lookup so you dont need `findViewById` inside `onBindViewHolder`